# find the first element in a list beyond some index and satisfying some condition

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I have as Input:

- A givenIndex
- A list

I want to find the index of the first positive element in that list but ignoring all the indices that are strictly smaller than `givenIndex`

For example if `givenIndex=2` and the list is `listOf(1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8, 2)`, the expected output is `4` (where the value is 6).
The following code gives the first positive element but It doesn't take into account ignoring all the indices that are smaller than `givenIndex`.

```kotlin
val numbers = listOf(1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8, 2)
val output = numbers.indexOfFirst { it > 0 } //output is 0 but expected is 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
val givenIndex = 2
val output = numbers.withIndex().indexOfFirst { (index, value) -> index >= givenIndex && value > 0 }
```